# Is it possible to publish similar apps under enterprise app deployment

Tags: iphone, publish

I have five iphone apps which have similar interface/functionality but for the use of five different business persons.They are doing same type of business. So the similarity in app. The app will be free to use by public.

Apple says 
1. Apps which appear confusingly similar to an existing Apple product or advertising theme will be rejected
2. Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program.
3. Apps that look similar to apps bundled on the iPhone, including the App Store, iTunes Store, and iBookstore, will be rejected.

Is these guidelines applicable for apps under enterprise app deployment ? Is it possible publish apps under Ad-hoc mode and give link of the app through another website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your app is same interface functionality. just add a db to it for different people. No need to publish it more than once. and issue regarding duplication on apstore, they already have billions of apps so no care for what purpose your app is. just differentiate the database as your goal is manage users separately.

Comment: Using same db is a nice idea. But , I wish to give different logo/background for each business. Also, I do not wish this app behave as business directory.

Comment: that is duty of server. I have worked on an app iQube Learning system. it is designed in such a way that for different users, different logos and designes are different. Point is that if you publish your app multiple times, it has differnt draw backs and the biggest one is that a negetive impact on your programming skill that you are not re using your code. just implement a webservice which will check the type or user and sends logos data on first visit/login and that logo data will be stored in local storage along with type of user. so that next time user will get access quickly.

Comment: and note, this will also work for users of different types on the same device. and user will be transparent to the logos as all this is being done on server side.

Comment: I think, I made mistake in my explanation.This apps are used to target customers of 5 different Painters. Each will have multiple customers. Each painter will have their own websites and app download page which directs user to different apps (to itune or somewhere else).  Painter 1 has 100 customers with Painter 1's app.Painter 2 has 75 customers with  with Painter 2's app. etc... 
The only difference in app will be the logo and background images.( These can also be pulled from server dynamically)

But the problem arise, when Customer A may be the client of Painter 1 and Painter 2 at a time.

Comment: I do not want to list Painter 1, Painter 2 etc.. in a single app and show their services.

I wish to upload these apps under my single account and give links to these apps from Painters sites.  As Apple do not support similar apps,
is there any way to publish the app other than through itune?
Is it possible under enterprise distribution? 

Sorry for my poor english.